# Альтернатива MySQL?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Где хранить данные, чтобы быстрее получать к ним доступ?

Вот у меня скрипт записывает все данные в MySQL, но я думаю, что есть какие-то альтернативные способы их хранения. Есть ли на самом деле и дайте, пожалуйста, краткое описание?

P.S. В большей степени интересуют способы хранения данных, которые смогут уменьшить нагрузку на сервер или увеличить скорость работы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Увеличение скорости работы возможно вследствие смены программного обеспечения, но на сегодняшний день сервера, подобные MySQL, очень хорошо оптимизированы. Чаще оптимизация некоторых серверов ярче выражена в каких-то типах данных или методах их обработки, вследствие чего необходимо отталкиваясь от своих данных копать в эту сторону.

Мне кажется, что наибольшего успеха вы добьетесь, если займетесь оптимизацией, заведете себе кэш и т.п.

Так же можно выбрать различные концепций, например [NoSQL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Answer (score 3):

- MariaDB (там есть разные движки, которые могут показать интересные результаты)
- Percona
- Drizzle (увы не для одного сервера)
- MongoDB
- Текстовые файлы (можно вынести некоторую небольшую информацию)

Answer (score 2):

Для *небольших* объемов информации подойдет [SQLite](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)

Comment: Дополню: часто используется как встроенное в ПО решение.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет желания возиться с решениями вида сервер-клиент, то MS Jet или как уже сказано SQLite.

Answer (score -1):

Можно записывать в файл, но это скорее правильно для временных данных.

Answer (score -1):

xml. А вообще почитайте [хранилище типа ключ-значение](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/nosql/103021/).

Comment: Быстрее?)

Comment: :) помоему это яма:)